# HLS - how to create a m3u8 manifest if I have ts files (Ubuntu)?

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

So I have found out I can create ts segments of a movie with this ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -i foo.mp4 -codec copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -map 0 -f segment -segment_list out.list -segment_time 10 out%03d.ts
```

But now I don't know how to create a m3u8 manifest file from ts files. Is there some open source library or command in Ubuntu that can do this for me?

If not, how difficult is it to create the m3u8 file in Python or some other language?

Comment: @Richard.I have one big .ts file how i can make them to segments and make m3u8 out of it without any transcoding ? could you show me the command for it ?thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FFmpeg can create m3u8 files. Just use arguments 'segment_list' for playlist name and 'segment_list_type m3u8' for creating m3u8 type playlist. Just make sure you are using latest ffmpeg version.

For more info look at this section in [documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment).

Comment: @kiri.How to split one big .ts file without trans-coding to many chunks and make m3u8 file out of it ?

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of ffmpeg pulled from git (tested with ffmpeg version git-2013-08-15-165b657) will generate the segment playlist file in m3u8 format if you specify the m3u8 extension for your output file when using the -segment_list argument.

```
ffmpeg -i foo.mp4 -codec copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -map 0 -f segment -segment_list out.m3u8 -segment_time 10 out%03d.ts
```

[ffmpeg stream segmenter reference](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment)

Comment: what's the purpose of "-vbsf h264_mp4toannexb"?